# Item status in sales order view not showing backordered after invoice is created

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, sales-order, sales-invoice

When we receive an order containing an out of stock item (that's allowed to be backordered) it nicely shows "Backordered" at 'Item status' in the backend sales order view.

[image: Backorder]

magento item status = backordered if the invoice is not yet created! When the invoice is created, the item status automatically changes to invoiced, see image.

magento item status = invoiced, even though still in backorder. This seems not logical to me and is definitely unwanted behavior. Even after the invoice has been created, I'd still like/need to know what products are in backorder.

[image: Invoiced]

Any idea how we can keep the message "backordered" on the order view?

Answer (score 0):

You can use event ***sales_order_save_after***, and inside the Observer put logic something like:

```
$oldstatus=$order->getOrigData('status');
$newstatus=$order->getData('status');

if($oldstatus == 'backordered' && $oldstatus != $newstatus) { //this checks if order was backordered and if the status is changed, it'll entered inside condition
    $order->setStatus($oldstatus); //sets back the status to old status 'backordered'
}
```

Comment: Any chance you can dumb it down for me and show which file to edit etc. Would be muchly appreciated. @natha